# Shell script is printing out the wrong for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I have to create a diamond but I keep getting the wrong output.

I have written 3 loops, the first is the height, and the second is the space, and the third is the asterisk

The second part is the second half of the diamond

#### Output

```
enter shape
diamond
width
5
 *  *  *  * 
 * *  * *  * * 
 * * *  * * * 
 * * * * 


 * * * * 
 * * *  * * * 
 * *  * *  * * 
 *  *  *  *
```

#### Script

```
"diamond")
echo "width"
read width

for ((h = 1; h <= $width; h++))
do

        for ((s = $width; s > h; s--))
        do
        printf ' '
                for ((a = 1; a <= h; a++))
                do
                printf '* '
                done
        done

echo ""
done

for ((h = $width; h > 0; h--))
do
        for ((s = $width; s > h; s--))
        do
        printf ' '
                for ((a=1 ; a <= h; a++))
                do
                printf '* '
                done
        done

echo ""
done
;;
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The `done` for your "space" `for`-loop is in the wrong place for both the top and bottom of the diamond:

```
for ((h = 1; h <= $width; h++))
do
    for ((s = $width; s > h; s--))
    do
        printf ' '
    done # <-- This should be here!
    for ((a = 1; a <= h; a++))
    do
        printf '* '
    done
    echo ""
done
```

I recommend running your script with `bash -x` to see what's going on.